# How to create a mask for a tensor based on dimension-wise condition

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have a `n` by `m` tensor and I want to create a `n` by `1` binary mask so that `mask[I]==0` if the row `tensor[i]` is all 0. How can I do this python pytorch?

Comment: Are you asking for Python or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you want something like this

```py
x = torch.tensor([
    [0,1,2],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,1,0]
])

mask = x.eq(0).all(-1).long()
>tensor([0, 1, 0])
```

if you want to keep the unit axis, you can add `keepdim=True`

```py
mask = x.eq(0).all(-1, keepdim=True).long()
>tensor([[0],
         [1],
         [0]])
```